# How to iterate all items in a given row in the DataTable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

How to iterate all `items` in a given row in the `DataTable` . I have the following code to iterate all rows, I want another For loop to iterate all cells in a given row ?

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

Next row
```

I can access each row, but I want to access each column on the row, as I don't know the name and the count of the columns ,..

Comment: have you checked any answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to loop through [DataRow.ItemArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). In `C#`, we can do it by following code:

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
     foreach (var item in dr.ItemArray)
       {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
       }
   }
```

This is equivalent to the following VB.NET code.

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    For Each item In dr.ItemArray
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: you can replace `var` by `object` or `Dim`

Comment: how to get index of a particular column inside dr.ItemArray?

Comment: Use `for` loop instead of `foreach`

Answer (score 4):

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    For Each column As DataColumn in dt.Columns
        Console.WriteLine(row(column))
    Next column
Next row
```

Answer (score -1):

your code is correct.
you cn use this code...

```
Dim tbl As New DataTable()
Dim datarow As DataRow

tbl.Columns.Add("column1")

datarow = tbl.NewRow()
datarow("column1") = "Data1"

tbl.Rows.Add(datarow)
For Each dr As DataRow In tbl.Rows
    For Each value In dr.ItemArray
       Label1.Text = value.ToString()
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score -2):

You can [use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) `DataRow.ItemArray` to do the job also

the code would look something like this

```
For Each item As var In Row.ItemArray
    //do something
Next
```

Comment: This code is not correct. value has the (inferred) Object type. There is no var in VB.NET.